# Get confidence intervals of an ets model via simulation

Tags: time-series

I am making a program to make the confidence intervals for an additive error additive trend model, based on the book *Forecasting with Exponential Smoothing* by Rob J. Hyndman.

The model of the series is $$y_t = l_{t-1} + b_{t-1} + ε_t$$ and it is said that one way of getting the intervals is by simulating paths and getting the quantiles.

I try to get the same intervals obtained by the `forecast()` function.
Does the forecast package use the simulation method when forecasting the models given by the `ets()` function?

In that case, for this specific model it is necessary to generate some random numbers with a normal distribution. Should I use the square root of the estimated $σ^2$ as the standard deviation for the `rnorm()` function? It is also said that in practice 5000 paths are simulated. What should be a suitable value for the `set.seed()` function in order to get always the same result?

What is the default seed value of the forecast function when generating random numbers?

Comment: Overall, I think this question is on topic, but questions just about R code are generally not on topic here, so you might not get answers to those sub-questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, prediction intervals are computed analytically if a formula for the forecast variance is available. See Ch6 of the book you cite (http://exponentialsmoothing.net). For a few models, the forecast variance is unknown and so it is simulated.

For the ETS(A,N,N) model you are using, the forecast variance is known and given on p82 of the book. The forecast distribution is Gaussian, so it is easy to compute prediction intervals.

In the `forecast.ets` function, you can set `simulate=TRUE` to use simulation instead of the analytic formula. This is explained in the help file.

You do not need to generate any random numbers yourself, it is handled by the function. You do not need to set the seed, it just uses the default value (which itself is arbitrary). If you want to get the same result all the time, set the seed to any integer you like.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that if simulate = TRUE, then every time I run that line, the results are slightly different. The program I was making (not using the forecast() function) had always different results and I wanted to have always the same output, but now I see that the forecast() function also yields different numbers when the simulation method is chosen and I noticed that the program I was making gives similar results to the ones obtained with the forecast() function. I wanted to have the forecast() function as a reference and I am glad that the result of the program was acceptable.